# ClassCastException when reading long value from JSON

Tags: java, android, json, classcastexception

I am using the JSON in my android app. When I try to the do the following:

```
long timeCompleted =0;
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            obj.put("TimeCompleted", timeCompleted);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The Value is saved fine.

But when I do this

```
try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsn);
            timeCompleted = (long)obj.get("TimeCompleted");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I get the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

because it thinks 0 is integer not long although I saved it as long

Why is this and how can I get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

```
object.get(YOUR_KEY)
```

use

```
object.getLong(YOUR_KEY)
```

`get()` returns `Obejct` whereas `getLong()` returns `long`

Answer (score 0):

You should use **[`getLong`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)**, which returns `long` whereas `get` give you `Object`

```
timeCompleted = obj.getLong("TimeCompleted");
```

And, you don't need explicit casting as well.